# Collection as out parameter

Tags: c#, collections

I'm very new to the concept of collections. I have a class object (`Officer`) that has several attributes, three of which form the name of the officer.

I also have a separate class object called `Company`, which is heirarchially positioned above the `Officer` object. A `company` contains a selection of Officers, so to display the names of the officers I need some form of reference between the two:

```
private List<Officer> officerList;
public void addOfficer(Officer off)
        {
            officerList.Add(off);
        }
```

Now, to actually return that data to another class, I need to either create a list (pointless), create a large number of `Officer` objects (inefficient), or return a collection.

```
public void getOfficerNames(out *something* names) //I want to use a collection 
                                                         //here... I think
        {
            foreach (Officer o in officerList)
            {
                names = o.Title
                      + o.ForeName
                      + o.SurName;
            }
        }
```

That's as far as I've got, as I'm having difficulty understanding
a) How to implement the collection and
b) If it's the right thing to do.

Comment: You could create a `List` of `String`s (i.e., `List<String>` to contain all the officer names. You can then add them by doing `list.add(o.Title + " " + o.Forename + " " + o.SurName)`. This is done in the for-loop. You declare your list before the for-loop. However, if you are using `out` the variable has to be declared in the calling function.

Comment: Why do you want to use an `out` parameter rather than a return value? It's very odd to use an `out` parameter in a `void` method. I'd also *strongly* recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, so using capital letters to start method names.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to create a list in another class to use with an asp:ListBox, using an `out` parameter is easier because I can form the list using a variable type rather than another entire list. However, reading that back, it barely makes sense to me, so I'll think about doing something different.

As for the .NET convention, I tried it. I think it looks horrendous personally, so I follow the convention up to a certain point. For example, I see no reason to avoid abbreviations if the meaning is obvious, regardless of how widely it is used. But that's just me, and I am a pedant.

Comment: If you ignore the .NET naming conventions, you will be making life hard for *everyone* else who reads your code. You may not like it, but you should still follow it. And no, I don't understand the first sentence of your comment either... "I can form the list using a variable type rather than another entire list" really doesn't make sense to me. There really is no reason to use an `out` parameter here... if you think there is, it's entirely possible you don't understand what `out` means. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not so sure that it is that much more difficult to read. I think there's certainly a point where acronyms and abbreviations drift into obscurity, but there is room for shorthand in some cases. For example, `win` on it's own could mean a few different things, however in the context of a method, we might have `win.Resize()`. It's pretty obvious there that this is a window, and in that context it's perfectly reasonable to use `win` and save yourself from typing-related ailments.

Comment: You're obsessing on the acronym part, whereas I never even mentioned that. On the other hand, you've completely ignored the part where I said to start your method names with capital letters. Note that local variable names don't become part of your API, so aren't nearly as important in terms of conventions - and I don't even remember seeing anything saying that local variable names definitely shouldn't use abbreviations. So, are you going to start following the conventions for public API members such as methods?

Comment: @JonSkeet Forgive me, I assumed you were referring generally to the convention as a whole. As for capital letters for public properties/methods, I do actually agree with it. However, I strictly follow the public/private conventions in code that is already written, and this is an extremely large and very old project that I am working with. The convention with this project is to specify private properties with an underscore, `_private` suchlike. In fact, my adoption of camelcase goes against it, but I find the benefit of camelcase significant in terms of readability.

Comment: I am referring to the convention as a whole (which as I say doesn't prohibit you from using abbreviations where appropriate for local variables, as far as I'm aware), but the only thing you've violated in the code you've posted is the method naming convention. So why is your public method called `getOfficerNames` instead of `GetOfficerNames`?

Comment: @JonSkeet because it was originally `getofficernames`, and I missed the capital G. It's pointless changing it, as it's going to be returned to lowercase when I'm finished. The meaning and ownership of the method is obvious, so in this case it matters only to the extremely pedantic.

Comment: @Wolfish: No, it matters to anyone reading the question later, who is used to .NET naming conventions. It's a distraction from the meat of the question - just like it would be a distraction to anyone using the API. Conventions make everything flow more smoothly, reducing unnecessary cognitive load. Don't forget that Stack Overflow isn't just a way of you getting an answer - it's meant to be building up a repository of good questions for future readers. Writing a good question which follows conventions is part of that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Put like that, you have a point. IRL, however, I see it as a point of procrastination. It might prove effective in test circumstances, but I have yet to see it make a difference in the real world. Perhaps I will soon.

Comment: Try using 3 different APIs each of which has decided to follow a different convention. The code becomes *horrible* to read. The .NET naming conventions are *very* well established and well documented - I would very strongly urge you to follow them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `out` to modify a [reference type passed to a function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx), so this will suffice:

```
public void GetOfficerNames(List<string> names)
{
    foreach (Officer o in officerList)
    {
        names.Add(o.Title + o.ForeName + o.SurName);
    }
}
```

Also, it would be more readable to just return the names:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetOfficerNames()
{
    return officerList.Select(o => o.Title + o.ForeName + o.SurName);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var names = new List<string>();

//...

names.AddRange(GetOfficerNames());
```

Or just:

```
var names = GetOfficerNames().ToList();
```

---

`out` is mainly used for value types, to [make them being passed by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). However it may also be used with reference types if you need to initialize them. So, in your case the example would look like this:

```
public void GetOfficerNames(out List<string> names)
{
    names = new List<string>();

    foreach (Officer o in officerList)
    {
        names.Add(o.Title + o.ForeName + o.SurName);
    }
}
```

and then it would be used like this:

```
List<string> officerNames;  // uninitialized
GetOfficerNames(out officerNames);

foreach (var name in officerNames)  // out guarantees officerNames
{                                   //  will be initialized here
    //...
}
```

This is however rarely needed, not very readable, and thus discouraged and rarely used.

Comment: +1. Additionally, I would encapsulate the officer name string concatenation within the Officer class, either by adding something like an Officer.GetName() function or possibly even overloading Officer.ToString(). Then if I want to get the officer name elsewhere in code I can ensure that I will get the same result and don't have to write the same code twice (mostly the former).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered returning a list of names as string?

```
public List<string> getOfficerNames()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>;
    foreach (Officer o in officerList)
            {
                names.Add(o.Title + o.ForeName + o.SurName);
            }
    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better served by makind this an enumeration if you want each officer name in a string accessable as an enumeration or list

```
public IEnumerable<string> getOfficerNames() //I want to use a collection 
                                                         //here... I think
        {
            foreach (Officer o in officerList)
            {
                yield return o.Title + " " + o.ForeName + " "+  o.SurName;
            }
        }
```